# A variation of the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following claim:

> Suppose $f$ is analytic in a deleted neighborhood $D$ of $z_0$ except for poles at all points of a sequence
>   $\{z_n\} \longrightarrow z_0$. (Note that $z_0$ is *not* an isolated singularity.) Show that $f(D)$ is dense in the complex
>   plane.

Here's my attempt.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} :  0 < |z - z_0| < \epsilon \}$. Assume that $f(D)$ isn't dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Then there exists a $w \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\delta > 0$ such that,

\begin{align}
|f(z) - w| > \delta \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \frac{1}{|f(z) - w|} < \frac{1}{\delta} \equiv g(z) < \frac{1}{\delta}
\end{align}

Now, for $\epsilon/2 > 0$, we have that there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,

\begin{align}
z_n \in B(z_0, \epsilon/2), \quad n \geq N.
\end{align}

Now let $\epsilon' < \text{min} \{ \epsilon/2, |z_1 - z_2|, \cdots , |z_1 - z_{N-1} \}$. We then have that $B(z_1, \epsilon')$ is contained in $D$ such that $z_1$ *is an essential singularity* of f(z), since the open ball $B(z_1, \epsilon'$) contains no other points from the sequence.

Consider the annular region $D' = \{z \in D : 0 < |z - z_1| < \epsilon' \}$. From the first equation, we have that,

\begin{align}
g(z) < \frac{1}{\delta}, \quad z \in D'.
\end{align}

Since $g(z)$ is bounded on $D'$, we have that $g(z)$ has (at most) an isolated singularity in $D'$. Therefore, we have that there is a function, $h(z)$, such that,

\begin{align}
g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z) - w} = h(z), \quad z \in D',
\end{align}

and that $h(z_1)$ is analytic. Rearranging the previous equation, we have that,

\begin{align}
f(z) = w + \frac{1}{h(z)} = \frac{h(z)w + 1}{h(z)} \equiv = \frac{A(z)}{B(z)}, \quad z \in D'.
\end{align}

Since $f$ has a pole at $z_1$, we have that $h(z_1) = 0$, implying that $|g(z_1)| = |h(z_1)| = 0$, contradicting that $|g(z)$ is never zero on $D' \subset D$.

Comment: This statement is covered by [Casorati-Weierstrass's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), and its proofs. Were you given a more restrictive version in class? Wow! Wikipedia also has a restricted statement (assuming holomorphic). Ignore the statement, just look at the proof.

Comment: @scentofthetrees I'm self-studying from a book. The theorem as stated in the textbook is: "If f has an essential singularity at $z_0$ and if $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z - z_0| < \epsilon \}$ , then $f(R)$ is dense in the complex plane.

Comment: @scentofthetrees I thought the proof of the CW theorem has to be amended in this case, since, in the context of the question, $f(z)$ doesn't have an isolated singularity at $z_0$ due to the presence of infinitely many poles in $D$. Therefore, I think I had to further zoom into a small enough neighborhood in $D$ in which $f$ may be considered to have an isolated singularity.

Comment: It doesn't have to be isolated, only a point at which on a punctured neighborhood the function is meromorphic. See the proof in the link.

Comment: Oh. I have read a more restricted version of the proof as of yet now then, I guess. I'll see the link.